# How to monitor Mongo DB cluster locally

Tags: mongodb, monitoring

I am looking for a free solution to monitor some key stats for my mongo db cluster.

1) No of read writes happening

2) Replication lags

3) Memory status

4) Time taken by read writes

etc
.
.

After spending a couple of days I know the commands which I can use to get the same.
Also there are a lot of hosted options which directly solve the above problem.
eg: the new free monitoring https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/free-monitoring/
Since I am not using the enterprise edition I am unable to find any good locally setup monitoring tool. I cant share the data over network, so need suggestions on how to setup local monitoring for the same.

Comment: Are you looking for reporting on these metrics or real time ? because there are a lot built in : Mongostat, mongotop, serverStatus, mongotail etc.. http://mongodb-tools.com/

Comment: Also SO is not really the place to ask for SW recommendations...

Comment: @Pogrindis: yes , I have checked all these tools, was looking for something to aggregate these results into a dashboard, also apart from mongostat and mongotop, the other commands like: serverStatus will have to be executed on each node right?